# OSGI Bundle for Interactive CLI console

Tags: osgi, equinox

I am new to OSGI world. I do already have OSGI bundles running and i want to create a new OSGI bundle and plug it in into my previous bundles. I want to create a bundle which should ask user about some input e.g Input number 1 and then after user inputs a number and press enter, it should ask again Input number 2 etc....... It would be better if separate CLI console is opened for my bundle but it should be able to communicate to other bundles as well. Can you please guide me in this matter. I am using Eclipse and equinox for OSGI.

Comment: Can you please provide some of the code you have already written for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

yahoo is your friend. You can follow this post but change it so it reads from BufferReader.readline instead of arguments you pass in when the application starts.

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99762.html

Would be useful if you posted some of your code.